# Can I use a magnetic air seal on an exterior door?

Tags: doors, insulation

It occurred to me it may be a good idea to air seal an outdoor door using a similar magnetic seal as refrigerator doors. I can't find this product available today. Maybe because it would make opening the door a challenge.

But any idea if this would work to prevent air leaks? Or is anyone aware of such products?

I have come across "magnetic strips for doors" but the magnet only attaches to a metal door and no magnet for the door frame, just a rubber sweeper. These can still leak air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnetic weatherstripping for doors is quite common. It attaches around the door in a grove that's part of the door trim. Inside the gasket is a magnet that pulls it tight to the door to form an airtight seal.

[image: weatherstripping]

That is a cross section view. The fishbone shape on the bottom goes into the door trim for a tight seal. The magnet is the dark part on top and is inside of the weatherstripping so that it pulls the vinyl or rubber tight against the door. Click through the photo for a sample Amazon product.