# How to make a subwoofer that is also a clothes closet

Tags: doors, cabinets, sealing, closet, speakers

I am building a tiny home and do not have room for a dedicated subwoofer. However, I am thinking about making a DIY multipurpose subwoofer/closet. I've read around that clothes can packed into a subwoofer as an alternative to using polyfill. If I make a sealed enclosure subwoofer, the question becomes how to build an airtight door that gives me easy access to my clothes.

Does this sound do-able? I'm thinking of using a refrigerator door gasket to [make the airtight door](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/21636/45730).

Comment: This is certainly interesting, but I still doubt it will work to quite the extent you hope. Clothes are more likely to act as baffles, damping the sound, and an airtight seal would just cause the closet to act like a closed tube, meaning some frequencies resonate *really* well while others are attenuated. I don't want to discourage you from trying this, but I do want to know what makes you think this will work. Also, I literally don't understand how you don't have space for a 12" cube *anywhere*.

Comment: Oh, drawing this out might help relieve some of my confusion.

Comment: I'm not an expert by any means, but the most common enclosure design the [airtight sealed enclosure](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/speaker9.htm). As for resonance, I don't believe enclosed woofers produce sound by making the whole enclosure resonate, but by vibrating the diaphragm. Woofer enclosures are built to dampen enclosure vibrations, otherwise you'd get an awful rattling sound. So yeah, I don't consider damping the inside a bad thing.

Comment: I really disagree on the "airtight" bit... Every home theatre (not car audio) subwoofer I've seen advertises the vent port. On smaller speakers, sealing appears common, but not for the massive amount of air a sub moves. You also misunderstand what I mean by resonance. I simply mean that a speaker in an airtight box will display strange resonant characteristics because it picks up the resonant frequencies of the box itself. Lastly, the damping I refer to is not the same as anti-vibration. That's the job of isolator mounts. I mean acoustic attenuation of dissonant frequencies.

Comment: For example: http://www.mobileinformationlabs.com/HowTo-1Woofer-Box-CAL%20Port%20lenth%201.htm